# HashMap using Generics

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have:

```
protected Map<String, ? extends Transaction> transactions = new HashMap<String, ?>();
```

However, I get a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,?> to Map<String,? extends Transaction>
```

I've tried some variations, including:

```
protected Map<String, ? extends Transaction> transactions = new HashMap<String, ? extends Transaction>();
```

All yield the same compilation error.

My goal is to have an instance of `Report` `abstract class` (extended by many different kinds of reports), accept multiple subclassess of the `abstract class` `Transaction`.

The types going into a single instance of an extended `Report` will all be the same type, for example `TRRReport extends Report` will need to accept `TRRTransaction extends Transaction` into it's `HashMap`, however `TDDReport extends Report` will need to accept `TDDTransaction extends Transaction` into it's `HashMap`.

How can I use a `HashMap` and `Generics` in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure you got those errors?

Comment: @Rohit yup... unless Eclipse is wrong...

Comment: You're misunderstanding variance.  You should not be using `?`.

Comment: @SnakeDoc. Or unless you're using nested generics instead. That declaration will give you a different error. You can't instantiate `HashMap<String, ?>`. Type mismatch is thing coming later.

Comment: @Rohit depending on how I try.. sometimes i get `Cannot instantiate the type HashMap<String,?>`.

Comment: @SLaks can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The point of `?` in generic parameters is when you want to store a collection of an unknown type in a variable.  This is called covariance.

You want a regular generic collection of `Transaction`s:

```
protected Map<String, Transaction> transactions = new HashMap<String, Transaction>();
```

Comment: this gives compilation error `Syntax error on token "Transaction", delete this token` pointing to the `new HashMap<String, Transaction>()`

Comment: That sounds very unlikely; what compiler version are you using?

Comment: I'm importing `java.util.Map` and `java.util.HashMap` and JDK 7_51.

Comment: Not true: say you have a class `Foo<T>` and you want to fill a collection with several derivatives of `Foo` and each have a `T` extending `Q` you can initialize a collection `ArrayList<Foo<? extends Q>>`, this won't work with `ArrayList<Foo<Q>>` since in that case you can't add `Foo<SubQ>`

Comment: @CommuSoft There is no nested generic type here. Makes a difference.

Comment: @RohitJain: I agree, however the first statement that the `?` at initialization is pointless is false. One needs to be very careful with such statements since they sometimes are applied to general.

Comment: @CommuSoft: No; that's because `Foo<SubQ>` is not `Foo<Q>`.  In other words, you have a `Foo` of an unknown type.

Comment: @SLaks: of course given `SubQ extends Q`. Indeed `Foo<Q>` is not `Foo<SubQ>`, but sometimes you don't mind the exact type, you only need to know for sure it has certain functionality. In that case the generic parameter is useful when creating a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing it with

```
new HashMap<String, ?>();
```

You can use diamond inference:

```
protected Map<String, ? extends Transaction> transactions = new HashMap<>();
```

In that case the javacompiler will find out what to write at the constructor side itself.

Comment: I get a type safety warning by doing this... is there no other option other than using `@SuppressWarnings` ?

Comment: Suppose the OP was using < Java 7. How would you rewrite the initialisation? : )

Comment: The safety warning is due to the IDE, this has nothing to do with the java compiler. And furthermore NetBeans for instance encourages using this (since when you change your mind, you don't have to modify that much).

Comment: @JoshM: The second variant is correct. Perhaps the wrong `Map` was imported?

Comment: @JoshM I am using java 7 and this code won't run on < java 7.

Comment: @CommuSoft you're second option works. I'm not sure what is "wrong" as SLaks said.. maybe he can elaborate?

Comment: Sorry; I misunderstood.  However, using `?` at all here is still wrong.

Comment: The `@SuppressWarnings` is part of IDE compilation. Of course not the type error. Some IDEs offer warnings to the users (for instance when you assign a variabe to itself)

Comment: @SLaks if i use explicit type of `Transaction` then i need to cast when putting in or taking out i think... using `?` may prevent that?

Comment: @SnakeDoc: No.  It sounds like you want to make your entire class generic, with a constraint.

Comment: @SnakeDoc: SLaks is right at this point. In general however, it is sometimes useful to use a `?` in a constructor (as I commented at SLaks answer). Personally however I think it's better to leave such generic things to the compiler if possible using diamond inference.

Comment: @CommuSoft No, the type-safety warning is provided by the compiler. It's not an IDE-specific feature, and it's warning about a specific problem (the possibility of heap pollution).

Comment: In this case yes. It is indeed risky to use `? extends T` when you want to add content to a collection and don't know the type to expect. I was just pointing out some warnings are IDE specific.