# Generics Map - avoid numerous casts

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have:

```
public abstract class Report {
    protected Map<String, Transaction> m = new HashMap<String, Transaction>();
    // more stuff
}
```

.

```
public class TRRTransaction extends Transaction {
    public String someMethodOnlyInTRRTransaction() {
        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void someInheritedMethod() {
        // do stuff
    }
    // more stuff
}
```

.

```
public class TRRReport extends Report {
    public void doSomething() {
        for (B b : m.values()) {
            query.setString(1, ((TRRTransaction) b).someMethodOnlyInTRRTransaction());
        }
    }
    // more stuff
}
```

I am trying to avoid having to explicitly cast into `TRRTransaction` all over the place. In my case, `TRRReport` will only ever be dealing with `TRRTransaction` in it's inherited `HashMap`. There are other types of `Report` subclassess, each deals with only it's related-type `Transaction`. Other than removing the `HashMap` from `Report` and moving it down locally into each subclass of `Report`, I'm not sure what else can be done.

I had a similar question, but I think I may have asked in the wrong way and didn't get a straight answer out of it: [HashMap using Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542487/hashmap-using-generics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your classes generic:

```
public abstract class Report<T extends Transaction> {
    protected Map<String, T> m = new HashMap<String, T>();
    // more stuff
}

public class TRRTransaction extends Transaction {
    public String someMethodOnlyInTRRTransaction() {
        // do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void someInheritedMethod() {
        // do stuff
    }
    // more stuff
}

public class TRRReport extends Report<TRRTransaction> {
    public void doSomething() {
        for (B b : m.values()) {
            query.setString(1, b.someMethodOnlyInTRRTransaction());
        }
    }
    // more stuff
}
```

Comment: bingo. thanks SLaks, this is what I was trying to do in yesterday's question-turned-match lol. ;-P I'll accept when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 4):

You could make your `Report` class generic, with an upper bound of `Transaction`.

```
public abstract class Report<T extends Transaction> {
   protected Map<String, T> m = new HashMap<String, Transaction>();
```

Then the subclass `TRRReport` can define `T` to be `TRRTransaction`:

```
public class TRRReport extends Report<TRRTransaction> {
    public void doSomething() {
        for (TRRTransaction b : m.values()) {
            query.setString(1, b.someMethodOnlyInTRRTransaction());
        }
    }
    // more stuff
}
```